# Prove the following inequality:$(2^u+1)^2(2^v+1)^2\leq 9(2^{uv}+1),$ for integer $u,v>5.$

Tags: inequality

**Problem:** $(2^u+1)^2(2^v+1)^2\leq 9(2^{uv}+1),$ for integer $u,v>5.$

**My Attempt:** $$(2^u+1)^2(2^v+1)^2=(2^{2u}+2^{u+1}+1)(2^{2v}+2^{v+1}+1)\leq (2*2^{2u}+1)(2*2^{2v}+1)$$
$$\Rightarrow (2*2^{2u}+1)(2*2^{2v}+1)\leq (3*2^{2u}+1)(3*2^{2v}+1)\leq 9*(2^{2u}+1)(2^{2v}+1)$$
$$\Rightarrow 9*(2^{2u}+1)(2^{2v}+1)\leq 9*(2^{2u+2v}+2^{2u}+2^{2v}+1).$$
After this step I don't know how to proceed. Please help.

Comment: In your second step, you used that $2^{u+1} \leq 2^{2u}$. However, because $u > 1$, we also have $2^{u+1} + 1 \leq 2^{2u}$. This will help reduce clutter significantly. (This is not, however, a full answer to the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to prove $9(2^{2u+2v}+2^{2u}+2^{2v}+1) \le 9(2^{uv}+1)$ equivalent $2^{2u+2v}+2^{2u}+2^{2v} \le 2^{uv}$

We have $2^{2u+2v}+2^{2u}+2^{2v} \le 2^{2u+2v + 2} \le 2^{uv}$ because $2u+2v + 2 \le uv$ for $u,v>5$